# ASP.net response.buffer does not work when set to false

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

After upgrading from IIS 6 to IIS 7 I recieved the following error in my web browser (Safari and similar errors in other browsers): "cannot decode raw data".  This error is temporarily fixed by changing:

```
response.buffer = false
```

to

```
response.buffer = true
```

I need to set this to "false" to in order to display files as they are generated instead of all at once (after a considerable amount of time).

I have tried increasing the bufferingLimit in the ApplicationHost.config file, but I still get this error when response.buffer is set to "false".  Does anyone know where this problem might be coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this problem is true, I also encounter this kind issue but cannot figure out a way. The reason of 'Response.Buffer= false' not working is that Microsoft modify their code in their later version IIS, i.e. IIS 5.0-7.5, in these versions IIS the Response.Buffer is handling true by obligation. So this is a false-positive setting for IIS, no matter you set buffer OFF or buffer.limit = 0. I think Microsoft screwing the clients because they want clients buy their latest software. Response.buffer = false can make the web application more powerful so they do want you use it anymore in old app. So let's say it's business trick.